# Bot Framework v4 - Bot Initiate Conversation

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot for Microsoft Teams using the Bot Framework SDK v4 for NodeJS. Is there a way that the bot can automatically initiate a conversation in a channel, rather than user initiating the conversation? My bot works fine when the user initiates the conversation. Any suggestions on how I can proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Teams calls that a "Proactive Message" (note: Bot Framework generally defines a "proactive message" as sending a user a message not related to current conversation, that you have a reference for. Teams lumps a few things into this category). You can read more about [how to use proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) from the official Teams docs. Or, more specifically, [creating a channel conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition).

The gist of it is that you need to [capture a `conversationUpdate` and check for a new member added to the conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition) or [fetch the team roster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-the-team-roster), then you [send the proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition).

Note: For MS Teams, the user or team will have to add the bot first:

> Bots can create new conversations with an individual Microsoft Teams user as long as your bot has user information obtained through previous addition in a personal or team scope. This information enables your bot to proactively notify them. For instance, if your bot was added to a team, it could query the team roster and send users individual messages in personal chats, or a user could @mention another user to trigger the bot to send that user a direct message.

Some developers come across `401: Unauthorized` errors when using proactive messaging, especially if the bot was restarted for some reason and the bot is attempting to re-initiate a proactive message. You can read more about preventing that [by using `trustServiceUrl` from this Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/proactiveTrustUrls/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) (this is my branch, which is being used to submit a Pull Request to update the Proactive Sample with `trustServiceUrl` info).

Comment: The need "the bot can automatically initiate a conversation in a channel" is not really "proactive messaging" because it needs to use a previous information, rather than only getting the identity from something else

Comment: @NicolasR You're right, at least for how Bot Framework defines it. However, [the Teams docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) kind of lumps it in with welcome messages and conversation initiation. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, it looks like some actions can be done depending on the channel

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my scenario, I send data from an external REST API to the bot running on Microsoft Teams. The bot receives this data and sends it to the appropriate channel. I was able to successfully achieve this functionality, however, the bot does not trigger a notification when this message arrives on Teams. Did anyone face such an issue? Or any suggestions on how I can alter the functionality?

Comment: What kind of notification do you want it to create? Chat or Activity, and on Desktop or Mobile?

Comment: ...and what code are you using to send your message from bot to user/channel?

Comment: @PratikMathur can you share the code on how you made the REST call to the bot running in teams ?

Comment: @PratikMathur can you share how you eventually solved the issue?

Comment: @AmitVig I was able to figure out a solution, noted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132206/microsoft-teams-botbuilder-how-to-create-conversation-in-another-channel/61144864#61144864

Comment: I figured this out a while ago but did not update the thread. Added the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a brand new conversation using the connector Client in the Botframework V4 and the Teams Extensions V4. In nodejs, you will find a solution in one of the comments for [this Github Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/574#). For anyone looking for a solution in **C#**, [here is a detailed blog post](https://doumer.me/proactive-message-bot-in-teams-with-the-botframework-v4-csharp/) about accomplishing this in C# version of the botframework.

**in nodejs :**

```
var conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity)
connectorClient = await createConnectorClient(context)

var conversationParameters = {
isGroup: true,
bot: conversationReference.bot,
channelData: (await teamsCtx.getTeamsChannelData()),
tenantId: teamsCtx.tenant.id,
activity: MessageFactory.text("Queue Summary Placeholder") as Activity
} as ConversationParameters

await connectorClient.conversations.createConversation(conversationParameters)
```

**In C#**

```
ConnectorClient _client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), await GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(turnContext), new HttpClient());
            var channelData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();

            var conversationParameter = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Bot = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
                IsGroup = true,
                ChannelData = channelData,
                TenantId = channelData.Tenant.Id,
                Activity = MessageFactory.Text(message)
            };
            var response = await _client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameter);
```

Comment: Read the blog post; one thing I wasn't quite clear on- at the end you show a screenshot of the bot working, you add it to a channel and then you write to the bot with an @mention and it replies to you, then later it starts it's own conversation. Was writing to it necessary for it to be able to complete setup and have access to the channel? Can whatever it grabbed (Guid?) as a channel reference be stored, so the bot can be shut down, started again and still be able to create new conversations in the channel?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah, writing to the bot is necessary at first. You can use  a database to persist your Data, using entityframework or what ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Really we need to know when you want the bot to send the message, the bot framework `TeamsActivityHandler` class provides multiple [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#methods) that you can utilise for example:

1. [onMembersAdded(BotHandler)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#onmembersadded-bothandler-): Registers an activity event handler for the members added event, emitted for any incoming conversation update activity that includes members added to the conversation.

Learn more about the events / methods you can utilise [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out and i wrote a bot controller that i can invoke on demand with the following code.

```
var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                IsGroup = true,
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    // this needs to come from the teams context.
                    Channel = new ChannelInfo(channelId),
                },
                Activity = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment)
            };
            // your service url may differ.
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceUrl) ? constantServiceUrl : serviceUrl, DateTime.MaxValue);
            var response = connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```