# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' when calling GetConversationMembersAsync for 1:1 private conversation

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Using the "Hello World" Microsoft Teams application sample from here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp

Trying to get a list of participants in a personal Microsoft Teams 1:1 chat after an action command from a messaging extension is invoked. Specifically, I need the e-mail address of the other participant, where I am the first participant.

This is the code from the messages controller:

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        using (var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl)))
        {
            if (activity.IsComposeExtensionQuery())
            {
                // Invoke the command handler
                var response = await MessageExtension.HandleMessageExtensionQuery(connector, activity).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return response != null
                    ? Request.CreateResponse<ComposeExtensionResponse>(response)
                    : new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                await EchoBot.EchoMessage(connector, activity);
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code from `MessageExtension.HandleMessageExtensionQuery` is as follows:

```
    public static async Task<ComposeExtensionResponse> HandleMessageExtensionQuery(ConnectorClient connector, Activity activity)
    {
        var query = activity.GetComposeExtensionQueryData();
        if (query == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Exception thrown here - error 403, there is no additional data except "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"
        var members = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(activity.Conversation.Id);

        var handler = GetCommandHandler(query.CommandId); // Gets a handler based on the command, irrelevant for this question
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return await handler.HandleCommand(query, members); // Should handle the command, but never comes here if we are in a 1:1 conversation
    }
```

The call to `GetConversationMembersAsync` fails with the following message: `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'` if the command is invoked from a 1:1 personal conversation between two people.

The call doesn't fail if invoked from a group channel.

How to get the list of participants of a 1:1 personal conversation? Do I have to authenticate my user through the bot in order to do that, or do I have to grant my bot some particular permissions? Does my account need to have some particular permissions in order to do this?

**EDIT - Added the app manifest**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "1ce95960-0417-4469-ab77-5052758a4e7e",
    "packageName": "com.contoso.helloworld",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Contoso",
        "websiteUrl": "https://8112abe3.ngrok.io",
        "privacyUrl": "https://8112abe3.ngrok.io/privacy-policy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://8112abe3.ngrok.io/terms-service"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Hello World",
        "full": "Hello World App"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Hello World App for Microsoft Teams",
        "full": "This sample app provides a very simple app. You can extend this to add more content and capabilities."
    },
    "accentColor": "#60A18E",
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "https://526d7c43.ngrok.io/configure",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "com.contoso.helloworld.hellotab",
            "name": "Hello Tab",
            "contentUrl": "https://8112abe3.ngrok.io/hello",
            "websiteUrl": "https://8112abe3.ngrok.io/hello",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "bfbcb607-5c29-4438-85a5-15e63fb0b273",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "bfbcb607-5c29-4438-85a5-15e63fb0b273",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "getRandomText",
                    "type": "query",
                    "title": "Get random text",
                    "description": "",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": [
                        "commandBox",
                        "compose",
                        "message"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "cardTitle",
                            "title": "Subject",
                            "description": "",
                            "inputType": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "8112abe3.ngrok.io"
    ]
}
```

**EDIT 2 - After trying, based on sample 51 - TeamsMessagingExtensionsAction**

As suggested, I tried with the [sample 51 called "TeamsMessagingExtensionsAction"](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action)
The code is:

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl);
var members = (await turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>().Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(
    turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
```

The exception along with the stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Conversations.cs:line 1462
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots.TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.ShareMessageCommand(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action) in D:\Visual Studio Projects\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\51.teams-messaging-extensions-action\Bots\TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs:line 68
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots.TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Visual Studio Projects\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\51.teams-messaging-extensions-action\Bots\TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsActivityHandler.OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionDispatchAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Teams\TeamsActivityHandler.cs:line 201
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsActivityHandler.OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Teams\TeamsActivityHandler.cs:line 88
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsActivityHandler.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Teams\TeamsActivityHandler.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 1158
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 182
```

**EDIT 3 - Tried with the sample 57**

So I have started with the [sample 57 called "TeamsConversationBot"](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) and TLDR; works in channel, doesn't work in a private conversation.

Here are the steps performed:
*Note: ngrok was already started using the command `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 3978` and my existing bot registration was already configured to listen on the given URL*

1. Updated the appsettings.json configuration for the project to use the Microsoft App Id and App Password from the Bot Framework registration.
2. Edited the manifest.json contained in the TeamsAppManifest with the required GUIDs, zipped it along with PNG icons into manifest.zip and uploaded to Teams App Studio using "**Import an existing app**", which resulted in a new application called "TeamsConversationBot"
3. In Teams App Studio, opened the new application for editing, went to "**Test and distribute**", clicked "**Install**" and then "**Add**" on the next screen.
4. Navigated to the above screen again, but instead of "**Add**" I chose "**Add to a team**" from the drop down, where I added the bot to the channel of the Team I am the owner of.
5. In Visual Studio, went to *TeamsConversationsBot.cs* and set a breakpoint in *MessageAllMembersAsync* method, on a line which says `var members = await TeamsInfo.GetMembersAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);`
6. Started the project, went to my channel in Teams, sent the "**MessageAllMembers**" to my bot, waited for the above mentioned breakpoint to be hit and observed that the said call succeeds, i.e. returns a list of members. **So far so good!**
7. Went back to Teams App Builder to edit my "TeamsConversationsBot" app.
8. In manifest editor, went to "Messaging extensions" tab and set up my existing bot to listen for messaging extension invocations.
9. Added a new action-based command with a defined number of parameters. Gave it an Id, named a parameter and input the other mandatory fields, doesn't really matter. For "select the context in which the compose extension should work" I chose "**Command Box**" and "**Compose Box**", ticked "**Initial run**" and clicked "**Save**".
10. Installed the app again using "**Test and distribute**" -> "**Install**" and then "**Add**" button.
11. In Visual Studio, added the following method to *TeamsConversationBot.cs*:

    ```
    protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var connector = turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>();
        var conversation = turnContext.Activity.Conversation;
        var members = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(conversation.Id, cancellationToken);
        return await base.OnInvokeActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
    ```
12. Set a breakpoint on the line which says `var members = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(conversation.Id, cancellationToken);` and start the project
13. Went to the channel, selected messaging extensions under the compose box and invoked the newly added command. This triggered the above breakpoint to be hit. Performed a step over and observed that `members` variable contained all members of the channel. **So that works too!**
14. Went to a private conversation between me and the other team member (where me and them both have sent messages to each other previously, to ensure the conversation is not empty), selected messaging extensions under the compose box and invoked the newly added command. This again triggered the above mentioned breakpoint to be hit. Performed a step over and **bam!** The call has caused an unhandled exception `Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`

Comment: Are you trying this in channel or personal chat? If it's channel, then could you please confirm if you have installed the app for the team which you are trying? Bot Id or Manifest would help to check it further.

Comment: Sorry for wrong asking, We are looking into your issue, In the mean time could you please give us some time will get back to you soon...

Comment: We tried your code it is working fine at our end we are getting the member , Could you please help to provide your bot id or app manifest so we can look into the issue further

Comment: If you are looking for the email id of the participant you can get it from *activity.From*  .

Comment: @DejanJanjušević I could see this potentially being a [TrustServiceUrl issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007896/bot-framework-v4-bot-initiate-conversation/55009555#55009555), since Trinetra is unable to reproduce. Can you try adding `MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl);` just before the `GetConversationMembersAsync` call?

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Also, note, that if this is a new Teams bot, you should base it off of [Samples 50-57](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore). BotFramework has recently absorbed all of the Teams/Bot integration to keep things more consistent and updated (the sample you're using was created by Teams when Teams and BotFramework were significantly more separated).

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT and Trinetra-MSFT thanks for your comments guys. I tried with TrustServiceUrl too, same result. I will try to make a new solution using the samples you linked. In the meanwhile, I will edit the OP with the manifest.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT unfortunately I get the same exception when I base the project off sample 51. Are there any specific API permissions I need to request? Those two which are requested in the manifest at the moment are results of desperate tries to nail it. See my 2nd edit for the exception stack trace.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević I'll try to repro this later today. Can you provide your `MicrosoftAppId` so I can look into this on the backend?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT the `MicrosoftAppId` is `"bfbcb607-5c29-4438-85a5-15e63fb0b273"` - thanks. The bot was created from within Microsoft Teams App Builder, no permissions what so ever were specified initially, I added these two (`Chat.Read.All` and `User.Read.All`) later in "App Registrations" of Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to get the list of participants in a 1:1 private conversation between two people when invoking an action-based messaging extension. The trick is to get the bot into the private conversation too.

I thought about that solution in the beginning but didn't know how, and since no one suggested it, I thought it wasn't possible in one go. But turns out I was wrong.

So in case anyone ever stumbles upon this kind of problem. here it is.

Originally I did this using a FetchTask action messaging extension (the action-based messaging extension where you don't supply the predefined list of parameters, but fetch the parameters using the bot).

But it can be done using a regular action with static parameters too, so let's make an example using the method `OnInvokeActivityAsync` that I used in the question. See comments in the code below for an explanation.

```
protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var connector = turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>();
    var conversation = turnContext.Activity.Conversation;
    IList<ChannelAccount> members;

    try
    {
        members = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(conversation.Id, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (ErrorResponseException ex)
    {
        // If the ErrorResponseException contains the response with status code 403, that means our bot is not a member of this conversation.
        // In that case, return an adaptive card containing the prompt to add the bot to the current conversation.
        // After accepting the prompt, the bot will be added to the conversation and we will be able to obtain the list of conversation participants.
        if (ex.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            return new InvokeResponse
            {
                Status = 200,
                Body = AddBotToConversation()
            };
        }

        throw;
    }

    // At this point, we have the list of conversation members
    var otherMember = members.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id != turnContext.Activity.From.Id);

    return new InvokeResponse
    {
        Status = 200,
        Body = await DoSomethingWithOtherMemberInformationAndReturnACard(otherMember, cancellationToken)
    };
}
```

The `AddBotToConversation` can be defined like this:

```
private MessagingExtensionActionResponse AddBotToConversation()
{
    var card = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 0))
    {
        Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
        {
            new AdaptiveTextBlock("We need to add the bot to this conversation in order to perform the requested action"),
        },
        Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
        {
            new AdaptiveSubmitAction
            {
                Title = "Continue",
                Data = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    // The magic happens here. This tells Teams to add this bot to the current conversation
                    ["msteams"] = new Dictionary<string, bool>
                    {
                        ["justInTimeInstall"] = true,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var invokeResponse = new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
    {
        Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
        {
            Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo
            {
                Card = new Attachment
                {
                    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                    Content = card
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return invokeResponse;
}
```

Just make sure the messaging extension is action-based, not search-based. Search extensions will not support this approach.

**EDIT** Last but not least, don't forget to add the `"groupchat"` scope to the `"scopes"` collection of your bot under the `"bots"` collection in the Teams App manifest.json file, or else you won't be able to add your bot to a private conversation.

Comment: I agree that this is a good workaround. Just be wary of setting any Forbidden InvokeResponse to `200`, especially if you're doing anything with OAuth. It shouldn't be a security risk, but might have some unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

**Response to Edit 3**

Sorry, it looks like I misunderstood what you were trying to do. You cannot do this with the Bot Framework. Technically, the bot is not part of a Personal conversation between you and another user. Therefore, it doesn't have permissions to get information about that conversation, even though it's available as a Messaging Extension.

You may be able to use [this Graph API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), although you'll have to deal with getting the the auth token on your own:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/<conversationId>/members
```

---

*Making this an answer because it's too long to comment and I think it should accomplish what you need. Please let me know if this works or not and I can edit this*

---

I didn't see anything on the backend by looking into your `appId`, so I'm not sure of what the actual cause of the problem is.

You shouldn't need any permissions set at all -- those are only for OAuth, which `GetConversationMembersAsync` doesn't need. You should only really need the scopes set in your `manifest.json`, which appear to be set just fine.

However, for your App Registration, you may need to ensure that this is checked, under Authentication:

[image]

If it isn't you can manually adjust your **App Registration's** Manifest, by setting this:

```
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
```

If none of that works:

Please try [Sample 57](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot), which has a [`GetMembersAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L101) function that accomplishes the same thing, but with the current BotFramework SDK. Just be sure to follow the README and set everything up as specified.

Let me know how it goes. If you need additional help, can you try explaining your reproduction steps in as much detail as possible? I'd like to try to reproduce this and want to make sure our steps match--it may also help me call out where you might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. the `signInAudience` was already set to `"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`. I will try with the sample 57 and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Still the same problem... Please take a look at my edit #3 of the OP

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Thank you for the detailed repro steps! It turns out I wasn't understanding your issue, until now. I've edited in an updated answer at the top of my current answer. Sorry that it can't be done.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević My mistake. I wrongly interpreted as either a "1:1 convo with the bot", despite your clear description.