# When invoking a messaging extension, can the conversation Id from Activity be matched with a chat Id from Graph API?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

For context, please read [this question, especially edit 3, along with the answer to edit 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866100/operation-returned-an-invalid-status-code-forbidden-when-calling-getconversati)

I'm trying to get my Teams bot to get access to a list of participants in a private 1:1 conversation between two people (me and anyone else having a conversation with me), by invoking a messaging extension. Can this be done at all?

I'm using the latest Bot Builder SDK (4.6.3 at the time of writing)

A messaging extension query is handled by `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync` method, which provides `ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity>` object, which allows me to access the current conversation object using `turnContext.Activity.Conversation` property. This conversation object has an Id which looks like this:

```
a:15ya3x9GGFwBZUxa5Kd8DZzJ3IaWypTbCYjRhRL6bRYb0NmG4flXunysvJZWKdrJi3QVRrG7xZcjmZ9csxzyoK5cXuJb0hq29EpONRk6gLE7vprBPsA3jLTKymSTCdAqp
```

Let's assume I have authenticated with the bot and that I've consented to these API permissions:

- Chat.ReadWrite
- User.Read
- User.ReadBasic.All
- email
- openid
- profile

I have a valid access token which I've obtained by calling

```
await botAdapter.GetAadTokensAsync(
    turnContext,
    oauthConnectionName, // the connection name as configured in the bot channel registration
    new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com" },
    turnContext.Activity.From.Id, // the Teams Id of the action invoker, a.k.a me
    cancellationToken);
```

Now when I call the Graph API endpoint, suggested by the linked answer, using the conversation Id above, I get an error 400 - bad request. With error description "Bad Request". Nothing more.
In this case, the call would look like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/a:15ya3x9GGFwBZUxa5Kd8DZzJ3IaWypTbCYjRhRL6bRYb0NmG4flXunysvJZWKdrJi3QVRrG7xZcjmZ9csxzyoK5cXuJb0hq29EpONRk6gLE7vprBPsA3jLTKymSTCdAqp/members
```

[The Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) confirms the same - code "BadRequest", message "Bad Request".

Now when I called `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats`, I have noticed that chat IDs look nothing like above. After an investigation, I found that the actual ID of the target conversation, as communicated by the Graph API, was

`19:62177c5c-7a61-44a5-9772-8d193a7f433f_71840467-a52d-4aaa-b15b-6fc89bd93a9b@unq.gbl.spaces`

So when the following call would be invoked: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:62177c5c-7a61-44a5-9772-8d193a7f433f_71840467-a52d-4aaa-b15b-6fc89bd93a9b@unq.gbl.spaces/members`, I was able to obtain a list of conversation members.

So what's the correlation between the ID given by `turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id` and the actual Id expected by the Graph API? I'd like to note that, as observed in this example, it's obvious the expected ID already contains IDs of conversation members without the need to call this API, with the format `<some-id>:<convo-member-id>_<my-id>@unq.gbl.spaces`

Comment: Can you double check you are looking at the right conversation? And, if so that you aren't mixing up the `from.id` with the `conversation.id`? When I compare Graph to my `turnContext` object, I see the same `conversation.id` in both.

Comment: @StevenKanberg are you sure about that, because your colleagues claim [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3019) that this is a completely normal phenomenon :) Since it is said that this is not supported the way I wanted, I am going to post a workaround as an answer in the next few days, based on the documentation bits I managed to gather.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević, It is not currently supported the way you wanted. It is in our backlog but right now there is no ETA for this.